# How to use mysqli to count 2 rows from same database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a chart where I want to display numbers of users banned and activated. I want to do it as simple as using php to count numbers of rows where `banned = 1` and another where both `activated = 1` and `banned = 0`.

Most of the solutions I've found  dont work for what ever reason, some is outdated, and some I cant figure out. I use PHP7 but dont know how much thats gone change any solutions other than the oldest versions with `mysqli` and `mysql`

1.

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS banned FROM users WHERE banned = '1'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['banned']." banned users.";

    $result->close();
```

2.

```
 $num_banned = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `banned` = `1`");
    $row = $num_banned->fetch_row();
    echo '#: ', $row[0];
```

3. `$num_banned = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned='1'");
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($num_banned);`

Comment: Maybe you show us some code? Or you expect us to write it for you?

Comment: @u_mulder we are talking about 3 lines of code, I cant realy show any examples because I'm not sure what I've tried is outdated

Comment: But you can't even show these three lines, lol

Comment: mysqli works in php 7...

Comment: Show what you have and what you've tried that failed.

Comment: @chris85 i have added one of the code I tried that I had less problems with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`cases`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to count your records.

```
select 
count(case when (banned = 1 and activated = 1) then 1 end) as activeban,
count(case when (banned = 0 and activated = 1) then 1 end) as activenoban,
count(case when (banned = 1) then 1 end) as banned
from users;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/450d04/13

Running that query you should have, counts for activated users that are banned as `activeban`, inactivated users that are banned as `activenoban`, and a count of all banned users `banned`.

Comment: Why `(select 1)` instead of just `1`?

Comment: after trying it out (atleast how I understood it). i get an error `mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in`

Comment: @Barmar I was getting errors on SQLFiddle when running it earlier but it works now there.

Comment: @martinj Whats your PHP? Example 1, 2, or 3 (note in 3 you've switched to procedural).

Comment: @chris85 Those are the examples I've used. All I want to do is to count rows where  `x = 1`, I dont have a php code for it. I had some problems making number 3 a full "code" `ctrl + k` stopped working for some reason

Comment: You only need to execute this once. Which example did you use and get that error on? Add you current execution to the question. Yea, the code formatting sometimes faults with ordered lists.